# Rails not rendering ajax response when I add a link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this controller that is responding to an ajax call made by a form 
Controller:

```
if @invite.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:success] = "Friend invited with success"
        redirect_to event
      end
      format.js
    end
else
    flash[:danger] = "Failed to create invite"
    redirect_to request.referer || events_path
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(:invite, url: invites_path, method: 'post', html: {class: "form-inline"}, remote: true ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => event_id %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email, "Email:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Invite", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the response:

```
$("#invites").append("<li> <%= @invite.attendee.email %> - Pending - <%= link_to 'Confirm your presence', confirmation_path(@invite), method: 'post'%>  </li>");
```

This response isn't working, every time that I click on submit button nothing happens and when I look at rails or chrome console there is no error message.
But I've tried to remove the link_to tag, and started to work fine. How do I get the response to work with link_to?

Comment: Check your server logs. Is there any errors there?

Comment: There's no errors in the server or in the chrome console, Petr.

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is there is an error when you call `@invite.save` but you don't have any error handling to see what went wrong. To help you debug, change that line to `@invite.save!` so that you get an exception if an error occurs, and you should see details in your log file.

Another trick to helping you debug an ajax response, is to remove all jquery and ERB code to ensure that your response is even getting rendered.  Change your response js.erb to simply be:

```
console.log('successful response');
```

Try these 2 things, and if you have nothing in your log files and no "successful response" in your chrome console, let me know and we can try other things.